# Understanding the output of MFCCs

Tags: r, signal-processing, mfcc

I am a beginner of signal analysis. I want to extract the MFCCs of a sound, because I read that MFCC is a good parameter for automatic speech recognition. So I tried that in `RStudio` like this:

```
wl=512
ncep=13
mfcc.peewit <- melfcc(peewit,sr=peewit@samp.rate,wintime = wl/f,hoptime = wl/f,numcep = ncep,
                      nbands = ncep*2,fbtype = "htkmel",dcttype = "t3",htklifter = TRUE,
                      lifterexp = ncep-1,frames_in_rows = FALSE,spec_out = TRUE)
```

It turned out a 13*30 data frame and I am confused about the output of MFCC. I thought MFCCs would be 13 actual numbers but here I got a data frame, is the data frame MFCCs? Or I did something wrong? Or, I read this somewhere else that the 13 in "13*30" is the discrete representation of 13 coefficients, is that correct?

Thank you for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The audio signal is a time-series. There will be one set of MFCC coefficients per hop. Typical hop times for speech is maybe around 20-50 ms. So the 13 dimension is MFCC, and the 30 dimension is time.